# How do I print in a fluent sentence in the main method the results of a method I created?

Tags: java, methods, printing

1. I created a method called showCharacter. The method takes a string and shows what character is at a given location in that string. Here is the code for that method:

```
    public static void showCharacter(String userStr1, byte charLoc)
    {
        System.out.println(userStr1.charAt(charLoc));
    }
```

2. In main, I want to ask the user to enter a string and then ask the user to enter a number that designates a position in that string (first letter, second letter, fifth letter, etc).

The part I'm having trouble with is, after all that I want to print to the screen "The letter at position USER_ENTRY is: CHARACTER_FROM_THE_METHOD_I_CREATED_EARLIER."

Here is the code currently in my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a String");
        String str = k.nextLine();
        int strLen = str.length();
        System.out.println("Please enter the character's position");
        byte i = k.nextByte();


        while (i <0 || i > (strLen -1))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Position. Enter a valid position");
            i = k.nextByte();
        }



        showCharacter(str, i);


    }
```

I tried writing:

```
        System.out.println("The letter at position " + i + " is " + showCharacter(str, i));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is ```showCharacter```?  Isn't writing that the crux of your problem rather than the actual printing to the screen?   I suggest you look at the ```charAt``` method of the String class.

Comment: showCharacter is the method I wrote myself. It looks like the code block didn't display correctly. I have the code for that written under number 1.

Inside showCharacter I already use charAt

After my showCharacter method does its thing I need to print the results in main. But I don't want to just print the character by itself, I want to print it in a nice fluent sentence like "The character is THIS"

Comment: Oh, right,  Sorry, I missed it. I can edit that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `showCharacter` method almost as originally written.

```
    public static void showCharacter(String userStr1, byte charLoc)
    {
        System.out.print(userStr1.charAt(charLoc));
    }
```

The difference is I used `print` rather than `println` because I don't want to wire in the assumption that the character must be the last thing on the line.  Just output the character.

In `main` after you have a valid position, do your output:

```
    System.out.print("The letter at position " + i + " is ");
    showCharacter(str, i);
    System.out.println();
```

That is, there are 3 parts:

1. Stuff before the character
2. The character
3. Stuff after the character (here nothing except end of line)